# How can I make the bottom margin of a div equal to its percentage-calculated right margin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin

I have an array of floating divs that fit 4 to a row. Their widths and right margins add up to 100%. Their bottom margins, however, are static. CSS below:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 23%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the value of the right margin and apply it to the bottom margin so they are always consistent?

Here is an example of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/kVZMU/

Comment: So you mean, the value of the right margin in pixels and apply it to the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `margin-bottom: 2%`?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/uVfRL/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).css('margin-right');
    $(this).css('margin-bottom', val);  
});
```

Via javascript, get your right margin and set it as the bottom margin.
http://jsfiddle.net/cxn9E/

Comment: There is no reason to use JavaScript here. The value for `margin-right: 2%` and `margin-bottom: 2%` are the same. (Namely '20.5667px')

Comment: @KevinBoucher I didn't even try this because I assumed margin-bottom detected 2% of the page's height. Your suggestion worked! May I ask why the 2% on margin-bottom is still determined by the width and not the height?

Comment: I was under the impression margin-bottom did not take that into account. Learn something everyday.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can set your bottom margin with respect to right margin.
Set it on document ready and window resize so it will be always consistent.

Try this

```
var setMargin=function(){
    var divItems=$('div.item');
    var marginRight=divItems.css('margin-right');
    divItems.css('margin-bottom',marginRight)
    }
$(document).ready(function(e) {
setMargin();
$(window).resize(function(e) {
   setMargin(); 
});
});
```

Check on http://jsfiddle.net/kVZMU/2/